# How to add AuthorizeAttribute on global level and exclude it for some Actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, action-filter

I need to check if an action have specific attribute, and I need do it in the following method :

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext) {

}
```

I know I can Check it here:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {

    filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AnonymousAllowedAttribute), true)
 ...
}
```

Does any one know how can I Get `ActionDescriptor` with `System.Web.HttpContextBase` object?

**UPDATE**

Actually I want if any of actions marked with `AnonymousAllowedAttribute` the  `AuthorizeCore` method return true or if possible don't run (I mean my override method).

Comment: Where is AuthorizeCore invoked?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov All the methods are in `public class GlobalAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {` that must be helped you

Comment: Short answer is you cannot get ActionDescriptor from HttpContextBase. But if you give more details about what you want, it is possible that i help.

Comment: Do you want to mark all methods with your GlobalAuthorizeAttribute and then exclude some methods with attribute AnonymousAllowedAttribute?

Comment: If its true, you did it wrong.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov No, I defined `GlobalAuthorizeAttribute` in `Global.asax`, then some of the actions marked with `AnonymousAllowedAttribute`

Comment: It will not work. I'll write how to do this later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you want you need to write and register new FilterProvider in your global.asax.
Example:

```
public class AuthorizeFilterProvider:IFilterProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        if (!actionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AnonymousAllowedAttribute), true))
            return new Filter[] {new Filter(new AuthorizeAttribute(), FilterScope.Action, 0), };
        return new Filter[0];
    }
}
```

global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ....
        RegsterFilterProviders(FilterProviders.Providers);
    }

    private void RegsterFilterProviders(FilterProviderCollection providers)
    {
        providers.Add(new AuthorizeFilterProvider());
    }
```

Now if any of your action is not marked `[AnonymousAllowed]` application think that it is marked as `[Authorize]` 
**PS:** Don't forget to mark `[AnonymousAllowed]` your log on and register actions :)