# How to disable global attribute for a specific action\controller in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Ive got an attribute registered in global filters. And I want it to be disabled for 2 actions. How can I do this?

Comment: Look at this question. It is similar to your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051321/how-to-add-authorizeattribute-on-global-level-and-exclude-it-for-some-actions/12055924#12055924

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle this:

1. If you have control over the code of the action filter you could modify it in order to test whether the controller action is decorated with some custom marker attribute (that you will create) and do not run in case it is. Then you will decorate the 2 controller actions with this marker attribute.
2. If you do not have control over the code of this attribute you could write a custom filter provider by implementing the [`IFilterProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ifilterprovider%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) interface and inside the [`GetFilters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ifilterprovider.getfilters%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method that you're gonna need to implement test whether the controller action is decorated with some custom marker attribute and not include your global filter in the result. Then do not register the filter as a global action filter but register your custom filter provider instead. Filter providers are very often used to provide dependency injection into action filters. For example here's [`an article`](http://thecodinghumanist.com/blog/archives/2011/1/27/structuremap-action-filters-and-dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-3) which illustrates that in details with StructureMap.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9963113/1033684 for an implementation of the first one